# How can I configure Amazon S3 CORS so that Firefox will load remotely hosted webfonts?

Tags: firefox, amazon-s3, cors, webfonts

I've been trying to set up Amazon S3 as a webfont file host in order to use webfonts on Tumblr.

The CORS configuration suggested by Amazon works fine for everything except Firefox, which is exactly the same situation prior to Amazon enabling this new CORS feature in S3.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://fonttester.tumblr.com/</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Is there a different configuration I should be using?

Comment: What happens if you drop the last '/' in your AllowedOrigin?

Comment: remove the authorization for the allowedheader. Just use `*`

Comment: Sorry, neither of these has worked in  my case.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the below

```
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

Comment: Sorry, but that looks exactly the same as what I included in my original post, only without some extra lines that AWS S3 adds automatically.

Comment: Why was I downvoted? Have you even tried it ? AllowedOrigin * allows requests from all domains. Specifically for fonts, in response to the OPTIONS request both AllowedMethod of GET and AllowedHeader * make sure fonts are loaded and MaxAgeSeconds specifies the time the response is cached. I use this and it works on my site - http://apps.facebook.com/sudokuquest/

Comment: I didn't actually downvote you rampr, but your follow-up comment did expand on your first and so is more useful. Unfortunately however, it's still not working for me. I have only tested on Tumblr so far, so I'll try out some other domains, see if that might be a reason.

Comment: I've tried it without success, it works for the preflight but not for the GET request. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505801/amazon-s3-cors-headers-only-show-during-options-preflight-and-not-during-get-r